# Is there a way to force ffmpeg produce an I frame while encoding a mjpeg stream to h264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am transcoding a mjpeg stream to a h264 one, and I hope the stream can be played anytime I put it to a player, as far as I know, I need an I-frame the time I connect to it to play the stream properly, is it possible? By the way, I invoke the ffmpeg binary using golang so I have full control of its input.

Comment: Lazy suggestion is to add `-g 1` to make intra-frame output, but probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: @llogan I am transcoding from mjpeg to h264, the main purpose of this operation is to reduce the bandwith consumption of this stream, so `-g 1` is not acceptable. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Your KF interval should be equal to the maximum latency you're willing to tolerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved this problem with insertion of black image, everytime I want an I frame, I insert a black image into the input, since a totally black image is with high possibility different from the normal input image(in my case), it cloud solve my problem well.